# Cannot start Meteor app in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, meteor

I have started a project in meteor. a simple counter. I cannot mange to run it on iOS simulator.

I have once managed it to run on the iOS simulator, but not now.

It has proved to be a headache long hours ago, so, I have felt it could be a good idea to ask it here. This situation is inconsistent.

I can view it from my desktop browser and with iOS simulator's safari. But most of the time when app launched, the simulator only shows the meteor splash screen with the spinner. Some times Terminal exists the command with saying it could not started app on simulator and suggesting running --verbose. I do so but nothing changes. In those most cases it serves the web app to the browser. On the other hand I can successfully start my app with android simulator.

I feel confused. After fourth time of writing same piece of this app It is here.
I do not have server code can that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try running with the `--verbose` option, with this option the full Cordova/Phonegap builds will be logged on console, also work for me when i cannot start the app on the simulator.

Comment: I had already tried --verbose as it was suggested by the cli. I am in doubt about this inconsistent behaviour, same code some times can be simulated on iOS simulator but sometimes cannot, is related to the system memory available at the time I try that.

Comment: OK that happend to me several times, and yes is the systems memory, try closing everything  and run `meteor run ios --verbose`, if dont work the first or second time keep trying